# creating a custom calendar with moment using days/weeks and headings

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, calendar, momentjs

I am creating a schedule component using moment and react. I have created a custom calendar. How do place the days of the weeks fixed at the top like a normal calendar? So if i pass the date object september, i want to render all the dates with the correct day of the week heading above each date. I have created a fiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/4dbwLg6b/

```
var dates = ['Thu Sep 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Fri Sep 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sat Sep 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sun Sep 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Mon Sep 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Tue Sep 06 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Wed Sep 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Thu Sep 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Fri Sep 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sat Sep 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sun Sep 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Mon Sep 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Tue Sep 13 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)',' Wed Sep 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)',' Thu Sep 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Fri Sep 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sat Sep 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sun Sep 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Mon Sep 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)',' Tue Sep 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Wed Sep 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Thu Sep 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Fri Sep 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sat Sep 24 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Sun Sep 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Mon Sep 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Tue Sep 27 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Wed Sep 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Thu Sep 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)', 'Fri Sep 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)']
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {


    return <div className="container">
       {dates.map(function(day){
     return(
     <div className="calendarDay">
     {moment(day).format('D').toString()}
     </div>
     )
     })}
    </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

this is what i have
[image]

this is what i want, days of week corresponding to date number. mon,tues,wed.....
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Got it using a table as headers, and converted weeks and days using moment

```
const startWeek = moment().startOf('month').week();
const endWeek = moment().endOf('month').week();


let calendar = []
for(var week = startWeek; week<endWeek;week++){
  calendar.push({
    week:week,
    days:Array(7).fill(0).map((n, i) => moment().week(week).startOf('week').clone().add(n + i, 'day'))
  })
}
```

Comment: `moment('2017-12-31').endOf('month').week();` return 1

Comment: thats because according to moment, it is
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631682/moment-js-thinks-that-2013-12-31-is-week-1-not-week-53

Comment: `for (var week = startWeek; week <= endWeek; week++)`

Comment: Your solution was very useful. Thanks. 

Few corrections to adjust to the perfect date....

... `for(var week = startWeek; week<=endWeek;week++){` and
    
... `moment().week(week).startOf('week').clone().add(i + 1, 'day'))`

Comment: I later realized you don't need to add one. When you convert each of those dates to actual date, it will be correct. `2022-01-29T23:00:00.000Z` gave me 30 when I extracted the date with moment.  

Try this..... `moment("2022-01-29T23:00:00.000Z").format()`, you'd get **2022-01-30T00:00:00+01:00**

Comment: `endWeek = startWeek > endWeek ? moment(date).isoWeeksInYear()+1 : endWeek;`

Answer (score 26):

Base on all the answers above:

```
const calendar = [];
const today = moment();
const startDay = today.clone().startOf('month').startOf('week');
const endDay = today.clone().endOf('month').endOf('week');

let date = startDay.clone().subtract(1, 'day');

while (date.isBefore(endDay, 'day')) 
    calendar.push({
        days: Array(7).fill(0).map(() => date.add(1, 'day').clone())
    });
```

Comment: is it compaitible with react?

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. The current accepted answer doesn't do well with the month of December in 2019.

Comment: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined?

Comment: @Martian2049 use moment library

Comment: Note that if your week starts on Monday you have to use `isoWeek` for `.startOf` and `.endOf`.

Comment: @Ben you just ended all my suffering with this comment - bless you

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer provided by caffeinescript I created this calendar that would also work around year boundaries.

```
const startDay = moment().clone().startOf('month').startOf('week');
const endDay = moment().clone().endOf('month').endOf('week');

var calendar = [];
var index = startDay.clone();
while (index.isBefore(endDay, 'day')) {
    calendar.push(
        new Array(7).fill(0).map(
            function(n, i) {
                return {date: index.add(1, 'day').date()};
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Apparenty, one day is added *before* the date is returned. Wouldn't this cause wrong dates in the output array?

Comment: This function does not include the last day since its the same as endDay. You can use the `isSameOrBefore` method like this: `index.isSameOrBefore(endDay, 'day')`

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version

```
function weekDays(month, year) {
  const endDate = moment().date(0).month(month).year(year);

  return Array(endDate.date()).fill(0).map((_, i) => moment().date(i + 1).month(month).year(year))
    .map((day) => ({ day, week: day.week() }))
    .filter(({ week }, i, arr) => arr.findIndex((info) => info.week === week) === i)
    .map(({ day, week }) => ({ week, days: Array(7).fill(0).map((_, i) => moment(day).week(week).startOf('week').add(i, 'day')) }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@d0whc3r's answer seems the most accurate. I have made some modifications

I have run unit tests to 100 calendar years from 2000 until 2100

> Dear reader, if you are in the year 2100, please run unit test until
>   the year 2200.

index.js

```
function weekDays(month, year) {
    const endDate = moment.utc().year(year).month(month).endOf('month');

    return Array(endDate.date()).fill(0).map((_, i) => moment.utc().year(year).month(month).date(i + 1))
        .map((day) => ({day, week: day.week()}))
        .filter(({week}, i, arr) => arr.findIndex((info) => info.week === week) === i)
        .map(({day, week}) => ({
            week,
            days: Array(7).fill(0).map((_, i) => moment.utc(day).week(week).startOf('week').add(i, 'day'))
        }));

}
```

index.test.js

```
let testAll = (month, year) => {
        const monthYear = moment().year(year).month(month)
        const firstDay = monthYear.startOf('month');
        const endDay = moment().year(year).month(month).endOf("month");
        const calendar = weekDays(month, year);

        describe("testing calendar", () => {
            it('check if first date is in first week / should be true', () => {
                expect(calendar[0]["days"].filter((day) => day.date() === firstDay.date())[0].format("YYYY-MM-DD") === firstDay.format("YYYY-MM-DD")).toBe(true);
            });

           it('check if end date is in end week / should be true', () => {
                expect(calendar[calendar.length - 1]["days"].filter((day) => day.date() === endDay.date())[0].format("YYYY-MM-DD") === endDay.format("YYYY-MM-DD")).toBe(true);
            });
        });

    }
    for (let y=2000; y < 2100; y++){
        for (let m = 0; m <= 11; m++) {
            testAll(m, y)
            console.log(m)
        }
    }
```

> P.S: I'm not an expert in javascript and it's my first unit test